# What word describes the shape of a whirlwind when seen from above?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english, literary-english

What word describes the shape of a whirlwind when seen from above?

- Swirl
- Whorl
- Radial

> The shape they make when seen from above resembles a radial pattern or even a whorl.

Comment: They refer to office cubicles. Yes, I know it makes no sense, but that's the sentence I'm translating. :(

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are referring to a _whirlpool_, not a _whirlwind_, if only because humans almost never see a whirlwind from above, but usually do see a whirlpool from above.

Comment: No, whirlwind is correct. To give some more background, the person is dead and is literally 'floating up'. :D

Comment: In any case, I would say that "whorl" is the best descriptive term for this shape. The two other words I would consider close would be "helix" and "corkscrew." Also note that a transected nautilus shell has this pattern.

Comment: Tornadoes look like snakes, and it doesn’t matter whether you’re looking at them from one place or the other.

Comment: @tchrist Really interesting comment, and I see what you mean. (Sounds like a comment from someone who has had a tussle or two with the real thing.)

Comment: Wouldn't a whirlwind seen from above just look like a cloud? That's certainly true of a tornado, and I think it would be true of smaller whirlwinds as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a *spiral* would be the right shape. This is two-dimensional, and the radius is proportional to the angle of rotation.

[A *helix* has parallel sides, i.e. could be drawn on the surface of a cylinder (not a cone), so is not quite right.]

Comment: +1 Yes, you're right about a helix. I admit I was grasping a bit, and had convinced myself that a helix could be something drawn not only on a cylinder, but also on a cone. Do you think there's a name for that type of structure as it would appear if it were indeed drawn on the surface of a cone?

Comment: If we are avoiding *swirl* and *whorl* (alternatives already mentioned in the question), then this is definitely a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

The shape of a whirlwind is an inverted cone. To be precise, it is simply a cone shape, but we usually say "inverted" because we *usually* think of cones with the pointed end on top. (Even though one of the most common cones in our lives is an ice cream cone, which usually points down.)

Comment: I think the idea here is that you are looking at the whirlwind from above, so it's not accurate to call it an 'inverted cone'.

Comment: Then your question really needs to be "the shape of a whirlwind _as seen from above_." This is especially necessary because, as I pointed out, most people never see it from above, and so would think only of the typical inverted cone shape; you need to be aware of this fact as you write. Even if this were not the case, you at least need to be aware that a whirlwind has different apparent shapes depending on the perspective of the observer. Imagine how very different it would look to someone who is being whirled around inside one!

Comment: You're right. Updated my post.

Comment: It certainly wouldn't look like Kansas.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not think me facetious if I say my immediate thought is 'whirl' - I'm not sure why you would need something different to describe it. Please see http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whirl

Comment: None of the definitions in the linked entry refer to a shape or form.  The closest thing that might make sense is *whorl*.